# php при добавлении в БД кракозябры

Tags: php, mysql

```
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
function queryMysql($query)
{
    global $connection;
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    mysql_set_charset("CP1251");
    if (!$result) die($connection->error);
    return $result;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `u0163707_megg`.`users` (
`user_id`, `user_status`, `user_email`, `user_pass`, `user_name`, `user_surname`, `user_avatar`)
VALUES (NULL, '2', '$email', '$pass', '$name', '$surname', '/front/img/users/user.png');";

queryMysql($query);
print_r($query);
```

добавляю записи в бд через ajax. При добавлении запись все русские буквы превращаются в `ÐÐ¸ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð°Ð¹`. Кодировка БД utf8_general_ci, как и кодировка всех столбцов, кодировка файла utf8

вывод в консоль запроса выводит:

```
INSERT INTO 'users' 
  ( 'user_id', 'user_status', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'user_name', 'user_surname', 'user_avatar') 
VALUES 
  (NULL, '2', 'derzik2010@mail.ru', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'Николай', 'Федоров', ' /front/img/users/user.png');
```

Comment: попробуйте в `function queryMysql($query)` убрать строку `mysql_set_charset("CP1251");`

Comment: Ваш код состоит из несовместимых команд разных расширений: mysql и mysqli. Ну и в принципе он непоследователен, вы зачем-то пытаетесь указать кодировку уже после того, как выполнили запрос.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk мдаа... так глупо себя чувствую.. взял код и старого проекта для Китая, и не удалил строчку..

Comment: хоть проблемы это и не решает, но все равно стыдно, что просмотрел такое

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо сообщить серверу в какой кодировке работает ваше клиентское приложение. Эта кодировка теоретически может отличаться от кодировки данных в базе, сервер БД сам умеет менять кодировку "на лету".

Если вы используете расширение mysqli, а кодировка веб-страниц UTF-8, то это делается так:

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

Обратите внимание на отсутствие дефиса между utf и 8 :) А если вдруг ваша веб-страница работает в windows-1251, то делайте так

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "cp1251");
```

Команду надо выполнить **один раз сразу после соединения с базой**.
Я заметил в вашем коде использование mysql_set_charset (без "**i**") каждый раз после выполнением запроса — это ошибка, оно не работает и не должно.

Comment: ваше решение не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас кодировка UTF-8, то зачем же вы устанавливаете её CP1251?

Comment: А это `Кодировка БД utf8_general_ci, как и кодировка всех столбцов, кодировка файла utf8` не видно в вопросе?

Comment: Да не заметил, дело в mysql_set_charset("CP1251");

Answer (score 1):

1) Нужно создать таблицу с кодировкой UTF-8:

```
CREATE TABLE users (...) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

2) Нужно в начале установить кодировку соединения через:

```
$connection->query("set names utf8");
```

Comment: Из вопроса: `Кодировка БД utf8_general_ci, как и кодировка всех столбцов, кодировка файла utf8`

Comment: @Victor я же написал, что кодировка таблиц у меня utf8, второй вариант попробовал, не помогло

Comment: @Nikolay, вынесите `mysql_set_charset("CP1251");` из функции и поставьте эту команду сразу после подключения к базе + замените в команде кодировку `CP1251` на `utf8`. +++ Не используйте расширение `mysql`, оно устарело и на современных версиях php не поддерживается. Используйте **PDO** или `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали, что отправляете запрос через ajax

Возможно проблема как раз в **ajax**, попробуйте явно указать `scriptCharset: "utf-8"` (предполагаю что у вас jquery), а также проверьте кодировку *js-файла скрипта* и кодировку *html-страницы* вызывающего данный скрипт